# Windows FOR command not expanding system environment variables

Tags: batch-file

I have been using this site for sometime and have found it quite valuable in finding solutions to scripting issues. Today I resolve to ask a question as I have not found my solution after exhausting 3 days here, on Superuser, and Googling. So much for all about me, now my point...

I have several installs of a program, each slightly different version or flavor. Each install has a text file defining variables for its use. One of these variables defines a folder for user specific settings, `USERSET=%APPDATA%\foo1\foo2`. Overtime these user settings can become corrupt. I want to be able to delete these folders with a batch file or script. In short, I want to search a directory for text files that contain a specific string which sets a variable that points to a folder, get the value of that variable and use it to remove a directory.

This is what I have so far:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in ('dir /b /s c:\foo\*.txt ^| findstr /i /f:/ userset') do rd /s /q %%G
```

The output looks like this:

```
H:\>rd /s /q %appdata%\foo1\foo2\USERSET   
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Apparently `%appdata%` does not expand?

Of course if I just type `rd /s /q %appdata%\foo1\foo2\USERSET` at the command prompt, it works.

I'm open to other languages, I am mostly familiar with Windows command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because environment variable expansion is done at parse time of a statement. While your `for` loop is running and `%%G` actually gets a value it's too late; variables have already been expanded.

You can work around this with a subroutine, I guess:

```
pushd C:\foo
for /f ...  %%G in (...) do call :process "%%G"
popd
goto :eof

:process
  call set "X=%~1"
  rd /s /q "%X%"
  goto :eof
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I've chosen this answer as the best because it opened my mind to using subroutines. I encountered additional environment variables such CSIDL_APPDATA which does not expand under the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply insert a `CALL` before the `RD`

```
....CALL RD ...
```

although I'd also try

```
....CALL ECHO(RD ...
```

first to verify - just for safety's sake.

Comment: Nice answer. It's simpler than the other. Thanks for responding so quickly. I did like the idea of a subroutine from the answer above. Your answer works just as well! And yes I did verify for safety's sake rd /s /q can be very unforgiving.